# How do run a java class if isn't terminal doing anything?

Tags: java, macos

I have made a simple hello world program on my Mac. I went to terminal and typed in

```
    javac ~/Documents/java/helloworld.java
```

Terminal pauses then does nothing. It doesn't have any errors or anything. What do you do to fix this?

Comment: If you were presented with a prompt again, then you compiled correctly. If not, the process is hanging for some reason. If you compiled correctly, you'll notice that you now have `.class` files for each `.java` file you compiled. You can run your program by typing `java /path/to/file/helloworld`; remember that you have to run the file which has your `main` method in it, and note that this time you do not specify the file extension (neither `.java` nor `.class`). `.class` is the compiled Java bytecode, ready to be executed by the JVM. `javac` is the Java compiler, `java` is the JVM I think.

Answer (score 2):

You have successfully compiled your program but you haven't run it yet.  There's nothing to fix; run it!

Assuming you haven't put your class in a package, run `java`:

```
java ~/Documents/java/helloworld
```

No ".class" on the class to run.

Comment: Well, then how do I run it?

Comment: @user2246668 `java ~/Documents/java/helloworld`

Answer (score 1):

It means that you compiled your program without any errors.

To run your program, you can do this:

```
cd ~/Documents/java/
java helloworld
```